# using older version of a shared linux library while compiling C

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, fann

I am trying to use libfann version 2.0.1 instead of the newest version 2.2.0, but could not figure out how to do so. Any thoughts on how to do that?

normally that works perfectly:

```
gcc fann_calculator.c -o run_fann_calculator -lfann -lm
```

where fann_calculator.c contains a program that calls a neural network.

Thanks

Comment: and the errors you're getting are......

Comment: Are both libraries installed?  How do you know you're not getting the result you want?

Comment: the error I get is about a feature in the newest version:           FANN Error 4: Error reading "cascade_min_out_epochs" from configuration file "/home/sifa/Desktop/CE//fann_network.net".
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @BrianCain yes both of the libraries are installed and I wanted to use the older one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends upon where the two libraries sit. If they are installed in the same directory (e.g. both installed in `/usr/lib/`) you'll probably get the youngest one.

I suggest to carefully read the [ld.so(8)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html) and [ldd(1)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man1/ldd.1.html) man pages. You certainly can trace what library is loaded (with e.g. the `LD_DEBUG` envirnonment variable). Don't forget to re-run [ldconfig](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) appropriately after library installation.

You could also play some `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` trick; for instance, set it to `$HOME/lib:/usr/lib` and install appropriate symlinks in your `$HOME/lib/` to the precise library you want. For instance, you might do

```
  ln -s /usr/lib/libfann.so.2.0.1 $HOME/lib/libfann.so.2
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

then check with `ldd run_fann_calculator` that you get the expected [version of the] `libfann` library.

Don't forget to read the [Program Library Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/). You might want to pass appropriate flags to [ld](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) such as `-rpath`. You may need to pass them using `gcc`, perhaps with [Gcc Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) such as  `-Wl`

Comment: Then use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` trick with symlinks from your `$HOME/lib` and use `ldd` to check that the correct library is loaded.